# Booking Process Issues - Stripe and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

OK, I have been trying to find the issue for the past 2 hours.. For some reason my bookings don't come through, not even notifications appear on the page.

When I click BOOK NOW, the page reloads and doesn't give me any errors, so not sure what am I doing wrong.

I'm adding the stripe to the booking path step by step. The BOOK NOW button was working fine on its own before, but now that I aded the card charges to it - it doesn't.

Any help is very welcome! Happy to provide additional information, if needed.

Thank you

**Reservations Controller**

```
def create
    room = Room.find(params[:room_id])
      if current_user.stripe_id.blank?
        flash[:alert] = "Please update your payment method."
      return redirect_to payment_method_path

        @reservation = current_user.reservations.build
        @reservation.room = room
        @reservation.price = room.price
        @reservation.total = room.price * days

        if @reservation.Waiting!
          if room.Request?
            flash[:notice] = "Request sent succesfully"
          else
            charge(room, @reservation)
          end
        else
            flash[:alert] = "Cannot make a reservation"
        end
      end
    redirect_to room
  end
def your_trips
    @rooms = current_user.rooms
  end
  def aprove
    charge(@reservation, room, @reservation)
    redirect_to your_trips_path
  end

  def decline
    @reservation.Declined!
    redirect_to your_trips_path
  end
```

**Reservations Controller - private**

```
private
  def set_reservation
    @reservation = Reservation.find(params[:id])
  end

  def charge(room, reservation)
      if !reservation.user.stripe_id.blank?
        customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(reservation.user.stripe_id)
        charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
          :customer => customer.id,
          :amount => reservation.price,
          :description => room.overview,
          :currency => "usd"
        )

        if charge
          reservation.Approved!
          flash[:notice] = "Reservation created successfully!"
        else
          reservation.Declined!
          flash[:alert] = "Cannot charge with this payment method!"
        end
      end

    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      reservation.declined!
      flash[:alert] = e.message
  end
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is the problem, but you have a lower case `declined!` in the `rescue` block of your `charge` method.  I think it should be `reservation.Declined!` to be consistent with the rest of your code.

Comment: Hey, it didn't work unfortunately.. This is soooo frustrating!!!! :( Lily

Comment: You might try checking your Rails sever to see if and where the request is hanging up.

Answer (score 0):

After checking `current_user.stripe_id.blank?` it looks like you are unintentionally returning all requests.

I would try this:

```
if current_user.stripe_id.blank?
    flash[:alert] = "Please update your payment method."
    redirect_to payment_method_path and return
end
```

If your model code depends on the record being saved before calling `Waiting!`, keep in mind that `@reservation = current_user.reservations.build` does not save the record.

The `rescue` block in your `charge` method also appears to be out of scope. That could be refactored into a begin-rescue-end block within the first if.

And if you aren't seeing notifications on the page, make sure your layout displays :notice and :alert somewhere.